# How to solve possibly one-to-one relationship issue - Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

I'm bit confused here, here is my bussiness logics:

When new user is added to a system it should belong to some company (only one company) so my users entity looks like this:

```
public class User : IdentityUser<long>
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }
    public long? CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string ProfileImageUrl { get; set; }
}
```

Basically when user is added there is a dropdown where admin can choose company which is related to that user and that is fine. (User is treated as employee of that company)

But after a while we realised that Every single company must have a commercialist (user) which is related to that company. So for example if there are some additional questions about products that company is selling, first person that we should contact is commercialist related to that company and my company entity looks like this:

```
public class Company : BaseEntity<long>, IDeleted
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public long? CommercialistId { get; set; }
    public User Commercialist { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have an issue here since I can't add two companies with same commercialist. For example commercialist John is covering two companies, Apple & Samsung.
But with this scenario it looks like I've created one to one relationship and John can cover only one of these companies.

How I could solve this to relate John with two or more companies that are under his support ? (without adding extra tables ?)

Thanks guys!

Cheers!

Comment: Future-proof yourself: add a `CompanyUser` table that has a UserId, a CompanyId, and probably a "role" ("commercialist" and "user" perhaps?)

Comment: Configure the relationships as two one-to-many relationships.

Comment: So far everything looks ok for me. The main question is can one company have 2 or more commercialists?

Comment: @Serge one company can have at a time only one active commercialist, so that is answer: only one commercialist on company.

Comment: @GertArnold how could I do it ? by adding extra table CompanyCommercialist for example ?

Comment: @Roxy'Pro And where this commercialist gets his salary? from all companies? What company he  has a vacation, medical insuarance and so on?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to  just to  add  IsCommercialist flag to User class.

```
public class User : IdentityUser<long>
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public bool IsCommercialist {get; set;}

    public long? CompanyId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(CompanyId))]
    [InverseProperty("Users")]
    public Company Company { get; set; }
  
    [InverseProperty(nameof(Company.Commercialist))]
    public virtual ICollection<Company> CommercialistCompanies {get; set;}

    public string ProfileImageUrl { get; set; }
}

public class Company : BaseEntity<long>, IDeleted
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public long? CommercialistId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(CommercialistId ))]
    [InverseProperty("CommercialistCompanies")]
    public User Commercialist { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty(nameof(User.Company)]
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users {get; set;}
}
```

but I am afraid that relations have to be defined manually, as I did, since EF will not be able to do it properly